# Search for all records that have a particular value using case insensitive in a JSONB array field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, jsonb

I'm using postgres database and trying to query all records with "Value"=>"Black" in this JSONB field. That field contain an array of objects, e.g. {"id"=>"1", "key"=>"size", "value"=>"P"}

How do I query(case-insensitive) this records?

This is my code so far

```
def by_feature_value(value)
  relation.where('features @> ?', [{ value: value }].to_json)
end
```

Records

```
#<ProductSku:0x000055de9cc01ba8
  id: 33,
  product_id: 3,
  code: "1234",
  ean: "12345",
  created_at: Mon, 30 Apr 2018 11:47:00 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Mon, 30 Apr 2018 11:47:00 UTC +00:00,
  features: [{"id"=>"2", "key"=>"Color", "Value"=>"Black"}]>

#<ProductSku:0x000055de9cc01ba8
  id: 33,
  product_id: 3,
  code: "1234",
  ean: "12345",
  created_at: Mon, 30 Apr 2018 11:47:00 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Mon, 30 Apr 2018 11:47:00 UTC +00:00,
  features: [{"id"=>"2", "key"=>"Color", "Value"=>"black"}]>,
```

Comment: You need to `downcase` both sides: `where('lower(features) @> ?', [{ value: value.downcase }].to_json)`. To improve the performances, I recommend you to `downcase` the `value` on write time (+ migrate current data), so later you can assume that every `value` in the `features`'s JSON is in lower case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer to this is

```
ProductSku.where('lower(features::text)::jsonb @> lower(?)::jsonb', [{ Value: value }].to_json)
```

Without type casting the first comment on your post does not work.